# scanf returns 0, even thought input is given

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read a list of integers with the following format (there is a space after each number)

```
8 6 
2 
5 
3 
7 
3 
5
```

However, when I try to read it, the number 2 is always 0.

EDIT:
I thought i didn't need the full code for this, but here's the full code to reproduce.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n; //=8
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int m; //=6
    scanf("%d", &m);
    int input_arr[m];
    int fenwick[n];

    //Makes input array
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        int v;
        scanf("%d",&v);
        input_arr[i] = v;
    }
    
    //Initializes fenwick tree
    for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i++){
        fenwick[i]=0;
    }
    
    printf("%d \n", input_arr[0]); //prints 0

    printf("%d %d\n",n,m); //prints 8 and 6
    
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        printf("%d ",input_arr[i]); //prints 0 5 3 7 3 5 
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/PW6f3J).

Comment: "scanf returns 0" but you have not checked the return value from `scanf()` function – the number of items successfully converted. It is an *essential* check.

Comment: I tried in ubuntu, the code prints `2 5 3 7 3 5 `. No issue for me

Comment: "Full code": did you `#include < stdio.h>`?

Comment: yes it is included, just forgot it. My bad

Comment: `i < n+1` should be `i < n`. You're writing outside the `fenwick` array.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't notice, and thought it was my input_arr that was causing trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is coming from incorrect for loop. When you do following:

```c
for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i++){
        fenwick[i]=0;
    }
```

it is overwriting the first element of array `input_arr`. Fix your for loop to:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fenwick[i]=0;
    }
```

and it should work. You need to read up on how stack allocations work.

Also, try following:

```c
for(int i = 2; i < n+2; i++){
    fenwick[i]=0;
}
```

which should overwrite two elements.

Another thing you can try is change the declaration order of two arrays and it will work even if your for loop for fenwick array is wrong.